How to replace a text in pyagme by pressing a key
i'm a french and young progammer.
I'm coding with pygame an interface for an fallout rpg tool. So i want to display a text object and after a key, the text in the object will change.
So this is my code (surely a bad one but it works at least for displaying text):
from FallR_personnage import*
import pygame


pygame.init()
son_jeu = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\FallR\\Fallout 2 Soundtrack - California Revisited (Worldmap on foot).mp3")
son_menu= pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\FallR\\Louis Armstrong - A Kiss to Build a Dream On.mp3")
son_creation_perso= pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\FallR\\Fallout 4 New Vegas - Doc Mitchell Theme.mp3")
son_menu.play(loops=-1, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0)
programIcon = pygame.image.load('Vault_boy.jpeg')
pygame.display.set_icon(programIcon)
fenetre=pygame.display.set_mode((1366,700))
fond=pygame.image.load("Fond_FallR.jpg")
fond1 = pygame.transform.scale(fond, (1366,766))#pour un 1080p(1920, 1080))
pip_boy=(0,240,0)
menu_color= (217, 175, 47)
font_0 = pygame.font.Font("JH_FALLOUT.TTF", 16)
font_1= pygame.font.Font("r_fallouty.TTF",16)
font_2=pygame.font.Font("TT0807M_.TTF",32)
text = font_2.render("Bienvue sur FallR ! Ceci est la fenetre de jeu", False,menu_color)
text_1="APPUYER SUR 1 POUR COMMENCER"
texte_1=font_2.render(text_1, False,menu_color)
SCREEN_WIDTH=1300
SCREEN_HEIGHT=700
text_rect = text.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2,SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.05))
text_rect_1 = text.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2,SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.1))
fenetre.blit(fond1,(0,0))
fenetre.blit(text,text_rect)
fenetre.blit(texte_1,text_rect_1)
sum_special=0
tableau_comp=[]
pv_max=0
poids_max=0
poids_actuel=0
inventaire={}


jeu=True
while jeu==True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jeu=False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                pygame.mixer.pause()
                son_creation_perso.play(loops=-1, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0)
                text_1="Rendez-vous à la console"
                texte_1 = font_0.render(text_1, False,pip_boy)
                special=création_personnage(sum_special)
                compétences=compétence_personnage(special)
                pv_max,tableau_comp,poids_max=fiche_personnage(special,compétences,tableau_comp)
    pygame.display.update()   
pygame.quit()






So when i start the program, it launches without any troubles but when i press 1, the window just block and freeze whereas the function plays normally and i can use it (the function is utilizing the console by the way).
